# Proving an Identity with Scalar Product

Tags: linear-algebra

How to prove following:

$$(u,v) = \frac{1}{2} \left\{ (u+v,u+v) - (u,u) - (v,v) \right\}$$

Hint: This identity implies that the following 4 properties define scalar product uniquely:

$i. (u,v) = (v,u),$ ii. $(u + v,w) = (u,w) + (v,w)$, iii. $(\alpha u,v) = \alpha(u,v)$, iv. $(u,u) = |u|^2.$

I tried to solve from the right hand side to obtain the left hand side and but I couldn't do much.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The bilinearity properties i–iv imply that (,) follows the [FOIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOIL_method) rule.

Comment: *Hint:* $(u+v, u+v) = (u,u+v) + (v,u+v) = (u,u) + (u,v) + (v,u) + (v,v)$

Comment: @MatthewLeingang FOIL rule?

Comment: link added.  It's an acronym taught in american schools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u+v,u+v)-(u,u)-(v,v)\right\}&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u,u+v)+(v,u+v)-(u,u)-(v,v)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u+v,u)+(u+v,v)-(u,u)-(v,v)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u,u)+(v,u)+(u,v)+(v,v)-(u,u)-(v,v)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(v,u)+(u,v)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u,v)+(u,v)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(2u,v)\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{2(u+v)\right\}\\
&=(u,v)\ \Box
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Use this

$$\langle u+v, u+v\rangle = \langle u, u\rangle + 2\langle u, v\rangle
+ \langle v, v\rangle.$$

Comment: Isn't that precisely what the OP is asking to prove?

Answer (score 1):

The correct identity is

$$(u,v) = \frac{1}{2} \left\{  (u+v,u+v)-(u,u) -(v,v) \right\}$$
and to prove it use that the inner product is a symmetric bi-linear form.

Comment: Yeap.. jst corrected it!

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u+v,u+v)-(u,u)-(v,v)\right\}&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{(u_x+v_x)^2+(u_y+v_y)^2-u_x^2-u_y^2-v_x^2-v_y^2\right\}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2}\left\{2u_xv_x+2u_yv_y\right\}\\
&=u_xv_x+u_yv_y\\
&=(u,v)\,\Box
\end{align}

Comment: Here you assume that the scalar product is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, you're right :(

Comment: Got it. I'll write up the answer.